# resizing and positioning issue with gridster and multiple highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I based my code attempt on the example here:  [Resize issue while gridster.js with highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811690/resize-issue-while-gridster-js-with-highcharts).

I set up Gridster with 6 Highcharts. While I see the individual charts, the resize functionality does not seem to work well especially after multiple resizings (often times the resize right angle is not in the lower right hand corner of the grid) and the charts seem to overlap rather than display the positioning characteristics that I saw in the gridster demos. (might it be a browser issue?)

I would be most appreciative if someone would advise me on how to reconfigure my jsfiddle code example to achieve expected Gridster performance with expected resize capability in the Highchart graphs.

Additionally, any hints on setting the background color of each chart separately in css would also be helpful.

Many Thanks

I set up a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yomi7/emm29qvn).

```
    <div class="controls">
      <button class="js-resize-random">Resize random widget</button>
  </div>

  <div class="gridster ready">
    <ul style="height: 520px; width: 550px; position: relative;">

        <li class="gs-w" data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2"data-sizey="4">
        <div id="container1" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin: 0 auto"</div>
      <span class="gs-resize-handle gs-resize-handle-both"></span></li>

      <li class="gs-w" data-row="1" data-col="3" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="2">
          <div id="container2" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin: 0 auto">
          <span class="gs-resize-handle gs-resize-handle-both"></span></li>

      <li class="gs-w" data-row="1" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
           <div id="container3" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin: 0 auto">
          <span class="gs-resize-handle gs-resize-handle-both"></span></li>

       <li class="gs-w" data-row="3" data-col="2" data-sizex="3" data-sizey="1">
           <div id="container4" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin: 0 auto">  
           <span class="gs-resize-handle gs-resize-handle-both"></span></li>

      <li class="gs-w" data-row="1" data-col="5" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="3">
            <div id="container5" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin: 0 auto"> 
          <span class="gs-resize-handle gs-resize-handle-both"></span></li>

        <li class="gs-w" data-row="1" data-col="5" data-sizex="1"data-sizey="3">
            <div id="container6" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin: 0 auto"> 
          <span class="gs-resize-handle gs-resize-handle-both"></span></li>    

    </ul>
  </div>


var gridster;

      $(function(){

        gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
          widget_base_dimensions: [100, 55],
          widget_margins: [5, 5],
          helper: 'clone',
          resize: {
            enabled: true,
            stop: function(e, ui, $widget) {
              Highcharts.charts[0].reflow();
            }
          }

        }).data('gridster');


        $('.js-resize-random').on('click', function() {
            gridster.resize_widget(gridster.$widgets.eq(getRandomInt(0, 9)),
                getRandomInt(1, 4), getRandomInt(1, 4))
        });

      });


      $(function(){

        gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
          widget_base_dimensions: [50, 50],
          widget_margins: [5, 5],
          helper: 'clone',
          resize: {
            enabled: true,
        stop: function(e,ui,$widget){
        Highcharts.charts[0].reflow(); // reflow the first chart
        Highcharts.charts[1].reflow(); 
        Highcharts.charts[2].reflow(); 
        Highcharts.charts[3].reflow();
        Highcharts.charts[4].reflow(); 
        Highcharts.charts[5].reflow();
          }
        }
      }).data('gridster');


        $('.js-resize-random').on('click', function() {
            gridster.resize_widget(gridster.$widgets.eq(getRandomInt(0, 9)),
                getRandomInt(1, 4), getRandomInt(1, 4))
        });

      });

$(function () {
        $('#container1').highcharts({
$(function () {
        $('#container2').highcharts({
$(function () {
        $('#container3').highcharts({
$(function () {
        $('#container4').highcharts({
$(function () {
        $('#container5').highcharts({
$(function () {
        $('#container6').highcharts({
```

Comment: Your demo seems to doenst work, You have many times $(function () {, only one is required, because it is the same as $(document).ready();

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 functions initializing gridster. The first one is causing the issue.

```
//first gridster initialization
var gridster;
$(function() {
  gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
    widget_base_dimensions: [100, 55],
    widget_margins: [5, 5],
    helper: 'clone',
    resize: {
      enabled: true,
      stop: function(e, ui, $widget) {
        Highcharts.charts[0].reflow();
      }
    }
  }).data('gridster');
  $('.js-resize-random').on('click', function() {
    gridster.resize_widget(gridster.$widgets.eq(getRandomInt(0, 9)),
      getRandomInt(1, 4), getRandomInt(1, 4))
  });
});

//second gridster initialization
var gridster;
$(function() {
  gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
    widget_base_dimensions: [50, 50],
    widget_margins: [5, 5],
    helper: 'clone',
    resize: {
      enabled: true,
      stop: function(e, ui, $widget) {
        Highcharts.charts[0].reflow(); // reflow the first chart
        Highcharts.charts[1].reflow();
        Highcharts.charts[2].reflow();
        Highcharts.charts[3].reflow();
        Highcharts.charts[4].reflow();
        Highcharts.charts[5].reflow();
      }
    }
  }).data('gridster');
  $('.js-resize-random').on('click', function() {
    gridster.resize_widget(gridster.$widgets.eq(getRandomInt(0, 9)),
      getRandomInt(1, 4), getRandomInt(1, 4))
  });
});
```

For the background colors you can add color style.

```
.white { background: white; }
.red { background: red; }
.blue { background: blue; }
.yellow { background: yellow; }
```

And add each of the styles by name to the classes of each "li" as follows:

```
<li class="yellow gs-w" data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2"data-sizey="4">
    <div id="container1" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin: 0 auto"</div>
    <span class="gs-resize-handle gs-resize-handle-both"></span>
</li>
<li class="red gs-w" data-row="1" data-col="3" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="2">
    <div id="container2" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin: 0 auto">
    <span class="gs-resize-handle gs-resize-handle-both"></span>
</li>
<li class="blue gs-w" data-row="1" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
    <div id="container3" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin: 0 auto">
    <span class="gs-resize-handle gs-resize-handle-both"></span>
</li>
<li class="white gs-w" data-row="3" data-col="2" data-sizex="3" data-sizey="1">
    <div id="container4" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin: 0 auto">  
    <span class="gs-resize-handle gs-resize-handle-both"></span>
</li>
<li class="yellow gs-w" data-row="1" data-col="5" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="3">
    <div id="container5" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin: 0 auto"> 
    <span class="gs-resize-handle gs-resize-handle-both"></span>
</li>
<li class="blue gs-w" data-row="1" data-col="5" data-sizex="1"data-sizey="3">
    <div id="container6" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin: 0 auto"> 
    <span class="gs-resize-handle gs-resize-handle-both"></span>
</li>
```