# How to resize Highchart Graph manually while maximizing the Gridster Widget?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, widget, gridster

I am using [**ManifestWebDesign**](https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster) 's **angular-gridster** for designing widgets in a dashboard. And I am using [**Highcharts**](http://www.highcharts.com/) to show the graphs on the widgets.

I have **size** and **maximum size** for all widgets. When I click on **Maximize** button of widget I am able to resize the widget, but the graph inside the widget is not getting resized. Although when I resize the widget by dragging the mouse, then widget and graph gets resized. Following is the code I am using -

```
ctrl.gridsterOptions = {
            margins: [10, 10],
            columns: 50,
            width: 'auto',
            resizable: {
                enabled: true,
                handles: ['n', 'e', 's', 'w', 'ne', 'se', 'sw', 'nw'],
                start: function(event, $element, widget) {

                },
                resize: function(event, $element, widget) {

                },
                stop: function(event, $element, widget) {
                    ctrl.resizeGraph(widget);                   
                    $scope.isMaximized = false;
                }
             },
             draggable: {
                enabled: true,
                handle: '.widgetHeader',
                start: function(event, $element, widget) {
                },
                drag: function(event, $element, widget) {
                },
                stop: function(event, $element, widget) {
                }
             }
    };


   ctrl.resizeGraph = function(_widget) {
        for(var a = 0; a < Highcharts.charts.length; a++) {
              Highcharts.charts[a].reflow();
         }
   };

   ctrl.maximizeWidget = function(_widget) {
        $scope.isMaximized = true;
        _widget.col = 0;
        _widget.sizeX = _widget.maxSizeX;
        _widget.sizeY = _widget.maxSizeY;

        ctrl.resizeGraph(_widget);
    };

    ctrl.restoreWidget = function(_widget) {
        $scope.isMaximized = false;
        _widget.sizeX = _widget.minSizeX;
        _widget.sizeY = _widget.minSizeY;

        ctrl.resizeGraph(_widget);
    };
```

I thought the problem is with the event, while maximizing the widget I am manually resize it, so event is not fired, so then I tried with `$(window).trigger('resize');` but still the graph is not resized.

How to resize highchart graph manually while maximizing the widget?

**EDIT - RESOLVED**

I am able to resize the graph using **setSize** method with **timeout**

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
            var _widgetHeight = $(widgetId).height();
            var _widgetWidth = $(widgetId).width();

            _chart.setSize(_widgetWidth - 20, _widgetHeight);
        }, 500);
```

Hope this will help to someone else also. Thanks

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811690/resize-issue-while-gridster-js-with-highcharts

Comment: Yes I already tried to trigger the event **angular.element($window).trigger('resize');**, but still it's not resized

Comment: did you tried >> resize: {
        enabled: true,
        stop: function(e, ui, $widget) {
          Highcharts.charts[0].reflow(); // reflow the first chart...
        }
      }

Comment: Yes, I have function **ctrl.resizeGraph = function(_widget)** which does that.